# Take output from Grep and select parts for Variables

Tags: bash, shell-script

Ok, there are similar questions, but not exactly what I am looking for.

I am working with Kubernetes, so the information is from that, but this question is for Shell Scripting, so please don't push me off to Kubernetes people. :)

I run the following command to get the information:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces | grep sonarqube-
```

Result Example:

```
default       sonarqube-664b4fd48-g6nvb                   1/1       Running   0          4d        10.233.64.6     local-node-0
```

Goal: What I want is to take the first 2 values (`default` and `sonarqube-664b4fd48-g6nvb`) and turn them into variables that I can use elsewhere in the script.

Command Sample I want to use the variables in is like:

```
kubectl cp <file> ${namespace}/${deployment}:/opt/app/extensions/plugins/
```

Thanks, and please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### generally

What will work in `bash` and in other shells is to set positional parameters from the output of the pipe:

```
set -f -- $(kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces | grep sonarqube- )
```

In this case, you can now access the variables as `$1`, `$2`, etc.

### specifc for bash

In `bash` it is possible to create an array variable, like so:

```
var=( $(kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces | grep sonarqube- ) )
```

The idiom is `var=( ... )`, in this case the output of your `grep` pipe.

You can then access elements of your array using the form `${var[n]}`, with `n` starting at zero.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks! (tried to up-vote, but need more street cred I guess).

Comment: @DennisChristilaw That's ok. The expected thing to do is to mark the answer accepted with the check mark.

Comment: As long as the first two words in the output don't contain wildcards... Something like `*` as the first output word would fill the positional parameters with the filenames in the current directory, which is not what you want. Use `set -f` first if that's a risk.

Comment: @ilkkachu - Quite right, The OP is explicitly and specifically asking about parsing the output of `kubectl`, but your comment is proper for me to amend my answer, thanks.

Comment: @user1404316 Even though the output was from kubectl, this question/answer helped in other applications too. Thanks to the answer and help, I now have something I can use for more than just kubectl output. :)

Answer (score 3):

With **bash**'s **`read`** function:

```
read -r namespace deployment other < <(kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces | grep sonarqube-)
kubectl cp <file> "${namespace}/${deployment}:/opt/app/extensions/plugins/"
```

Comment: Very good.  This approach nicely avoids the common bash traps of unexpected _word splitting_ and _pathname expansion_.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this (with predictable output columns), I usually reach for awk.  Something like this might be useful:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces | awk '/sonarqube-/ { cmd=sprintf("kubectl cp <file> %s/%s:/opt/app/extensions/plugins", $1, $2); print(cmd); system(cmd); }'
```